# List is not refreshed after i delete an item in android

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh, notifydatasetchanged

Hello i am new to `android` and working on a demo of `Custom ListView`,I have made an `adapter` ,a `ListItem` custom and binding to my `Listview`,All things working perfectly but i want to remove item when i delete it from the `list`

**Adapter**

```
public class TimelineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;


    public TimelineAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, R.layout.list_item_post);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    public void setData(List<Post> data) {
        setNotifyOnChange(true);
        clear();
        if (data != null) {
            addAll(data);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override 
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Post post = getItem(position);
        PostListItem view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view =  (PostListItem) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_post, parent, false);


        } else {
            view = (PostListItem) convertView;

        }
        view.setPost(post);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

**fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        total = 0;
        mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);
        ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).allChildrenArePullable().listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

        mProgressBarLoading = (ProgressBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
        mTextViewNoItems = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textViewNoItems);

        mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());

        mListViewTimeline = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewTimeline);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mProgressBarLoading);

        mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);
        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mListViewTimeline.setOnScrollListener(this);

        //  mListViewTimeline.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        mListViewTimeline.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        Activity activity = getActivity();

        if(activity != null) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    //Do something after 100ms
                }
            }, 1000);


            mTextViewNoItems.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);

                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
                    Log.d("CLICK", "REFRESH");

                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Loader<List<Post>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        mTimelineLoader = new TimelineLoader(getActivity(), mListViewTimeline);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return mTimelineLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Post>> arg0, List<Post> data) {


        mTimelineAdapter.setData(data);

        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
        mTextViewNoItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBarLoading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mListViewTimeline.setEmptyView(mTextViewNoItems);

        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(0);

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, TimelineFragment.this);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Post>> arg0) {

        mTimelineAdapter.setData(null);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

**ListItem**

```
if (which == 2) {

                    if (mPost.postUser.userID == sharedConnect.mCurrentUser.userID) {
                        // Log.e("Remove Post", "Success");


                        //Added by jigar..
                        tfragment = new TimelineFragment();
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                        builder1.setMessage("Are you sure?");
                        builder1.setCancelable(true);

                        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                "Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();

//open = false;
                                        final AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> deleted = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                                            @Override
                                            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                                Connect sharedConnect = Connect.getInstance(getContext());
                                                sharedConnect.deletePost(mPost.postID);


                                                return true;
                                            }

                                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

                                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Deleted",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                tfragment = new TimelineFragment();
                                                tfragment.mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                            }
                                        }.execute();


                                    }
                                });

                        builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                "No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                        //  open = false;
                                    }
                                });

                        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                        alert11.show();


                        //end
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste your list item delete code. I cant see one :) and why are you calling notifyDataSetChanged(); in getView??? and moreover you are creating a new instance of the fragment and reloading thye adapter of that new instance, instead what you should do is get the existing fragment instance which is already loaded and reload its adapter simple :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari-can i send you the code?if possible?pls save me brother..:(

Comment: Carry on :) Send it or post it here only bro that will help everyone to guide you :) Simply post your delete code thats enough If that isn't enough we will think about code sending ok ???

Comment: @sulphuricAcid Try my solution below and let me know in case of concern

Comment: @how do i get position on my custom listItem class,pls see my existing code.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari-ok i am posting my delete code..

Comment: @SandeepBhandari-hello Please see my edit frend.

Comment: @sulphuricAcid ...On item click listener, OR onCLickListeners both give you the position and that you have to pass in the ARRAYLIST.remove("position") method ... If it is helpful for ,you than plz upvote or accept my below answer

Comment: why are you calling notifydatasetchanged so many times, you have to call that when you are adding or deleting a row from the listview

Comment: @Awadesh-thing is that i have made a custom listitem and make a seprate class for it,I am doing delete function in that.so can you please help me how to do it from that class?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha-i have not used onItemclicklistener as not needed..!!!

Comment: @sulphuricAcid ..than , you have used the OnCLickListener...??

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha-it doesnt make sense of using it when its not needed..why should i use it when i am doing nothing to open onclick..!!!

Answer (score 0):

implement onResume() method and load the adapter in onResume() method and notify data set changed

Comment: Hemant-Thanks you for quick reply,But can you tell me where to write i mean i am having custom class for mt listItem and doing delete from it,So?

Comment: You have to write onResume() in class in which you are loading the adapter for the list view.

Comment: I am setting adapter in my fragment and have used pulltorefresh.

Comment: mTimelineAdapter = new TimelineAdapter(getActivity());mListViewTimeline.setAdapter(mTimelineAdapter);
        mTimelineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   put this code in onResume() method in fragment

Comment: @hemant-i have used your code.but nothing happened..:( actually when i am doing pulltorefresh my list gets refreshed as per i need.So can you help me from that code inside pulltorefresh?

Answer (score 0):

First use the `adapter.notifiDataSetChanged()` carefully. It should be used when you are adding or removing a row from the list.

In order to delete an item from the list, set `onItemclicklistener` on your `ListView`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
        });
```

from this you will get the position of clicked item that you want to remove.

Now define a method in your adapter

```
   public void deleteRowFromUi(int position) {
    dataList.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this method from the activity using instance of the adapter in the activity